# Proving sufficiency by showing ratio of statistic pdf to sample pdf is independent of unknown parameter

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, scale-invariance, factorisation-theorem

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid random variables with densities given by $$ f_{x_i}(x|\theta)=e^{i\theta - x}\mathbb{I}_{(i\theta,\infty)}(x), $$ when $x>i\theta $ and $x=0$ otherwise. Let $T$ be the statistic $$ T=\min_i(X_i / i). $$
My plan is to find the density function of $T$ and show that the ratio of the density of $T$ to the joint density function of $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is free of $\theta.$

To get the density function of $T$, I am going to first find the density function of $$S=S(X)= (X_i/i)_{i=1}^n$$ and then determine the density function for the first-order statistic, $T$. I want to perform a transformation of variables between $X$ and $S$, so I have that $$ f_i(S_i) = e^{i\theta - iS_i}i\mathbb{I}_{(\theta,\infty)}(S_i) $$
My first question is, *is this a proper transformation of variables?* And 
second, *does anyone know a more efficient way to prove that this statistic is sufficient, or is this the ideal method of proof?*

Comment: You want your transform to make $i$ disappear from the distribution, not to make it appear in more places!  Once you've done that, your course  forward may be clearer.

Comment: The definition of $S$ is incorrect, it should be the vector of $X_i/i$'s.

Comment: The $X_i$'s are only independent as you've written the density, not iid.

Answer (score 2):

The joint density of the sample $X$ is
$$\prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i|\theta)=\exp\left\{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\theta-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right\}\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{I}_{(i\theta,\infty)}(x_i)$$
or
$$\exp\left\{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\theta-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right\}\mathbb{I}_{\theta\le\min\{x_i/i\}}$$
This should be enough to establish sufficiency, with no need for the change of variables from $X$ to $S$.